# Custom sorting 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array whose entries represent an employee including the name of their manager, sort of like this:

```
var array = [["Name", "Manager"],
["Leonard", "Penny"],
["Penny", "Professor Proton"],
["Sheldon", "Bernadette"],
["Raj", "Penny"],
["Professor Proton", "Professor Proton"],
["Howard", "Bernadette"],
["Bernadette", "Professor Proton"]]
```

If the employee and the manager are the same, it means that the person is highest up in the hierarchy. What I want to achieve is to sort each employee below their manager, alphabetically. In other words, the output I want is this:

```
[["Name", "Manager"],
["Professor Proton", "Professor Proton"],
["Bernadette", "Professor Proton"],
["Howard", "Bernadette"],
["Sheldon", "Bernadette"],
["Penny", "Professor Proton"],
["Leonard", "Penny"],    
["Raj", "Penny"]]
```

My attempt was to use `array.sort(compare)` with the following "compare" function:

```js
var array = [
  ["Name", "Manager"],
  ["Leonard", "Penny"],
  ["Penny", "Professor Proton"],
  ["Sheldon", "Bernadette"],
  ["Raj", "Penny"],
  ["Professor Proton", "Professor Proton"],
  ["Howard", "Bernadette"],
  ["Bernadette", "Professor Proton"]
];

function compare(a, b) {

  if (a[0] === a[1]) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (b[0] === b[1]) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (a[0] === b[1]) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (b[0] === a[1]) {
    return 1;
  }


  if (a[0].toLowerCase() < b[0].toLowerCase()) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

console.log(array.sort(compare));
```

Unfortunately, what I get as output is just an array sorted alphabetically by the name of the employee. Plus, the "header" is included in the sort as well, which I want not to happen.

What am I doing wrong, any tips or alternative suggestions other than using `Array.prototype.sort()`?

Please, kind soul, help me!

Comment: Just, can you make the snippet working ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment and apologies, I haven't used the snippet feature much in the past. I have amended it and you should be able to run it now and see the output :)

Comment: no problem x) thanks ! that's perfect

Comment: Just, I don't understand why a "Professor Proton" is after "Bernadette" (in the required output), can you explain ?

Comment: Hey, actually, Professor Proton is supposed to come before Bernadette, because he is her "manager". In fact, Professor Proton is supposed to be at the top of the list (because he is the only one who is "his own manager" (there will always only be one unique person in the list satisfying this condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort you have described is basically a flattened tree structure.

Here building the tree by reference in a `Map`, pushing top-level elements (`employee` === `manager`) to the tree, then flattening using a queue.

I expanded the dataset to include more properties as an example based on your comment on Nina's answer.

```js
const input = [
  ['Name', 'Manager', 'Shift', 'Language'],
  ['Leonard', 'Penny', 'Day', 'en'],
  ['Penny', 'Professor Proton', 'Day', 'en'],
  ['Sheldon', 'Bernadette', 'Night', 'en'],
  ['Raj', 'Penny', 'Night', 'en'],
  ['Professor Proton', 'Professor Proton', 'Swing', 'en'],
  ['Howard', 'Bernadette', 'Night', 'en'],
  ['Bernadette', 'Professor Proton', 'Day', 'en'],
];

const [head, ...temp] = input;

const map = new Map(temp
  .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
  .map(([, m]) => [m, []]));
  
const tree = [];
for (const [n, m, ...rest] of temp) {
  const o = { employee: [n, m, ...rest], children: map.get(n) };
  if (n === m) {
    tree.push(o);
  } else {
    map.get(m).push(o);
  }
}

const res = [head];
while (tree.length) {
  const { employee, children } = tree.shift();
  res.push(employee);
  tree.unshift(...(children ?? []));
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a tree and get the items in depth-first traversal. This (new approach) works without changing the payload.

```js
const
    sort = array => {
        const
            t = {},
            getManager = data => data[0] === data[1] ? '' : data[1],
            getData = manager => (t[manager] || [])
                .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
                .flatMap(data => [data, ...getData(data[0])]);

        array.forEach(data => (t[getManager(data)] ??= []).push(data));

        return getData('');
    },
    data = [["Name", "Manager"], ["Leonard", "Penny"], ["Penny", "Professor Proton"], ["Sheldon", "Bernadette"], ["Raj", "Penny"], ["Professor Proton", "Professor Proton"], ["Howard", "Bernadette"], ["Bernadette", "Professor Proton"]],
    result = [data[0], ...sort(data.slice(1))];
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work flawlessly! Thank you so much, Nina! I really have no idea how or why this works :D Hence I cannot even adjust it to my particular situation (the problem from my question was simplified, in reality each employee has more information other than just their name and name of their manager, such as shift, language, etc.), but I guess I'll spend the next couple of hours figuring it out :) Cheers!

Comment: @finaslonchas, sorry. please see edit. now it take the given data without mutating it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your goal because your expected results and your explaination don't line up (but it's probably just me not seeing it). But here's something I wrote that I feel is meeting your criteria?

```
const input = [
  ['Name', 'Manager'],
  ['Leonard', 'Penny'],
  ['Penny', 'Professor Proton'],
  ['Sheldon', 'Bernadette'],
  ['Raj', 'Penny'],
  ['Professor Proton', 'Professor Proton'],
  ['Howard', 'Bernadette'],
  ['Bernadette', 'Professor Proton'],
];

const sort = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(el => [el[1], el[0]]) //swap employee and manager
            .sort() //sort by the first element (i.e. manager)
            .map(el => [el[1], el[0]]) //swap back employee and manager
            .sort((a,b) => b[0] === b[1] ? 1 : -1 ); //move element to front if employee is the manager
}

console.log(sort(input));
```

It's result is as follows which is different to your expected results but meet the criteria:

```
[["Professor Proton", "Professor Proton"],
["Penny", "Professor Proton"],
["Bernadette", "Professor Proton"],
["Raj", "Penny"],
["Leonard", "Penny"],
["Name", "Manager"],
["Sheldon", "Bernadette"],
["Howard", "Bernadette"]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Basically, I have three levels in the hierarchy: level 1 = Professor Proton, level 2 = Bernadette & Penny (they report to Professor Proton), level 3 = Howard, Leonard, Raj, Sheldon (they report to either Bernadette or Penny). What I want is for Professor Proton to be at the top and then below Bernadette, then Howard and Sheldon (in alphabetical order). Then I want Penny to appear (she comes alphabetically after Bernadette and they are on the same level), then Leonard and Raj in alphabetical order. Sorry if I was unclear in my question (was on my second joint).